# How to get boot time from Diagnostics-Performance

Tags: powershell, event-viewer

I'm trying to read boot duration from `event viewer` via powershell. This is the command i use:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational"; id=100}
```

But I get this error message:

```
Get-WinEvent : No events were found that match the specified selection criteria.
At line:1 char:15
+ ... ootevents = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="Microsoft-Window ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-WinEvent], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchingEventsFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand
```

Comment: please format your question using the code tags inside the editor. This will help with readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this information, you must run PowerShell as Administrator.

Then the below will probably do what you want:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational"; Id=100} -MaxEvents 10 | ForEach-Object {
    # convert the event to XML and grab the Event node
    $eventXml = ([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event
    # output 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Computer' = $eventXml.System.Computer
        'BootTime' = [int64]($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'BootTime'}).InnerXml
        'BootFinished' = [datetime]($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'BootEndTime'}).InnerXml
    }
}
```

The output will be something like this:

> ```
> Computer BootTime BootFinished      
> -------- -------- ------------      
> YourPC   118733   12-6-2019 15:17:42
> YourPC    40259   12-6-2019 11:40:11
> YourPC    43884   12-6-2019 6:00:27 
> YourPC    46158   11-6-2019 12:26:17
> YourPC    37759   11-6-2019 10:00:30
> YourPC    53178   11-6-2019 6:49:03 
> YourPC    49745   10-6-2019 16:25:59
> YourPC    39130   10-6-2019 11:14:59
> YourPC    57165   10-6-2019 6:57:30 
> YourPC    48230   9-6-2019 11:03:02
> ```

<sup>P.S. `'BootTime'` is the number of milliseconds. The date format `d-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss` is the default on my Dutch computer</sup>

Comment: Was this possibility removed from Windows 10 20H2? The script is not running?

Comment: @user10191234 I don't have that update yet, so i cannot day.. what is _not running_? just this script? Nothing at all?

Comment: you script worked fine until version 2004, I believe it gets its values from event 100 in Event Viewer-> Diagnostics Performance->Operational, event 100 is not present on my PC so it is not running and it is not running in Insider Preview 20231 either due to the same reason.

Comment: @user10191234 I cannot check because I do not have that update yet. Seems strange that Microsoft removed that information or maybe have relocated it to another log though..

Comment: The feature was brought back in the Insider Preview build 21286.